# Tons of Twitter rows in my database

Tags: database, mysql, twitter, posts

I have 264,307 "http" (post_type = http) rows in my wp_posts table. 99% of those have them have this post_title:

```
GET http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/@xcentric.json?count=100
```

and "error" as the post_status.

Can I simply delete these without it affecting my site? My wp_posts table is 5gb!

Thanks

Comment: I'd be more worried about why are they there in the first place...

Comment: Agreed. Pretty sure they came from a plugin which I've disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bait-and-switch approach to deleting all those rows:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_posts_new LIKE wp_posts;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO wp_posts_new SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type'http'
AND post_title<>'GET http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/@xcentric.json?count=100';
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts RENAME wp_posts_old;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new RENAME wp_posts;
```

Now start using you website.

When you are absolutely sure `wp_posts` is working fine, you can then delete old file:

```
DROP TABLE wp_posts_old;
```

or you can keep it around for a few days and drop it later.

If you want the old table put back right way, switch it back in like this:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts RENAME wp_posts_new;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_old RENAME wp_posts;
```

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2012-01-05 17:27 EDT**

To DELETE http posts that have twitter in the post_title

```
CREATE TABLE wp_posts_new LIKE wp_posts;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO wp_posts_new SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE NOT (post_type='http' AND LOCATE('twitter',post_title) > 0);
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts RENAME wp_posts_old;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new RENAME wp_posts;
```

Comment: Let me ask you this: how would I grab any post_type 'http' that had "twitter" in the post_title (instead of the full URL)? Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like the updated code is keeping the post_type='http' rows with "twitter" and deleting the others... is it possible to reverse that? Thanks again!

Comment: I updated it by adding NOT around the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Thanks Rolando, that works! I think I also got it to work by using "Not Like":

`CREATE TABLE wp_posts_new LIKE wp_posts;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO wp_posts_new SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type='http' AND post_title NOT LIKE '%twitter%';
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts RENAME wp_posts_old;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_new RENAME wp_posts;
`

Answer (score 1):

Is there any `post_content` for those rows? Presumably they were made by some Twitter plugin, so see if there's one installed and if it's set to active or inactive. If the data isn't being shown or used anymore on the site / blog, you should be able to just remove those rows since they no longer serve a purpose.

Comment: Oh, and since it's a Twitter time-line, the data will still be on their server so it won't just be _gone_ if you remove it from your WordPress database.

Comment: It does have some post_content but it looks like code:
[http://cl.ly/1N1I140e021c3s3Q421H]

I feel pretty confident they came from a plugin which I disabled yesterday. Since disabled there haven't been any more posts.

Thanks stealthy.

Comment: Is is OK to mention which plugin you think was doing this?

Comment: Twitter Widget Pro but I'm on an old version of both the plugin and WordPress (2.9.2) so that is probably more to blame. Working on upgrading now.